# How can I get this data format using $project

Tags: mongodb

Input data:

```
{ name: 'java', count: 3},{name: 'JavaScript', count: 6}
```

Expected result:

```
{ java: 3, javaScript: 6}
```

How can i achieve this inside a mongodb project method in aggregating the data accordingly?

Comment: I don't think $project can do this. You need some kind of group/reduce here.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I think it is possible using $arrayToObject operator, check out my solution